# PHP mail template in Laravel, 'src' is not working into <img> tag

Tags: php, laravel

PHP mail template in Laravel,  'src' is not working into  tag.

```
$message = "<html><head></head><body>";
$message .= "<img src='link-image.jpg' alt='' /></body></html>";

$headers = "From: $from_email";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Any idea what is getting wrong?

Comment: Append `"\r\n"` at the end of each header.

Answer (score 1):

You can you like this code on controller.

```html
<img src="{{ asset('uploads/images/image.png') }}" />
```